Clarification of user_date for Linux VS Windows
I am struggling with user_data on Terraform for AWS.
I don't understand why what works for Ubuntu does not work for Windows.
For my Terraform that launches Ubuntu, I have the following for aws_instance:
user_data                   = filebase64("userdata.sh")

The contents of userdata.sh is:
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install nginx -y
echo "$(hostname)" | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html

This works fine.
When I try a Windows AMI, I change to the following:
user_data                   = filebase64("userdata.ps1")

The contents for userdata.ps1 is:
<powershell>
Remove-Item -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*" -Force -Confirm:$false
"hostname is: $env:COMPUTERNAME" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html"
</powershell>

I am using a custom Windows AMI with IIS pre-installed and still getting the default IIS start page (i.e. the script did not run)
I do see it in the user data through the EC2 console.
Not seeing any errors...
I tried without the  tags and tried other things I tried in different posts like:

using a txt extension
using a file template

I didn't find the Terraform documentation helpful for this specific issue.
